# PyQt5 button in second window not working

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am writing a cipher program in Python using PyQt5, that also has email functionality. In the program, there are 2 windows, and the goal of the second window is to add a new contact to the json file. When I click on the button in the second window, the program does not register the click.

As a second question, I am also having trouble getting the new contact info dumped into the correct spot in the file.

Here is my second window's code:

```
class AddContactWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        self.setStyleSheet(Window.StyleSheet1)

    def init_ui(self):

        self.TitleLab = QtWidgets.QLabel('Add New Contact')
        self.NameLab = QtWidgets.QLabel('Name: ')
        self.NameLe = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.CodeNameLab = QtWidgets.QLabel('Code Name: ')
        self.CodeNameLe = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.EmailLab = QtWidgets.QLabel('Email address: ')
        self.EmailLe = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.KeyLab = QtWidgets.QLabel('Key: ')
        self.KeyLe = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.SubmitBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add Contact')

        h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box.addStretch()
        h_box.addWidget(self.TitleLab)
        h_box.addStretch()

        h_box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box1.addWidget(self.NameLab)
        h_box1.addWidget(self.NameLe)

        h_box2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box2.addWidget(self.CodeNameLab)
        h_box2.addWidget(self.CodeNameLe)

        h_box3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box3.addWidget(self.EmailLab)
        h_box3.addWidget(self.EmailLe)

        h_box4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box4.addWidget(self.KeyLab)
        h_box4.addWidget(self.KeyLe)

        h_box5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box5.addStretch()
        h_box5.addWidget(self.SubmitBtn)
        h_box5.addStretch()

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addLayout(h_box)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box1)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box2)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box3)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box4)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box5)

        self.setLayout(v_box)
        self.setWindowTitle('Creat New Contact')

        self.SubmitBtn.clicked.connect(self.submitBtn_click)
        #self.SubmitBtn.clicked.connect(self.test)

        self.show()

    def test(self):
        self.close()

    def submitBtn_click(self):
        print('Processing')
        data = {}
        data['Name'] = "New Contact Name"
        data['CodeName'] = "New Code Name"
        data['Email'] = "New Email Address"
        data['Key'] = "TestKey"
        with open('Contacts.json', 'a') as fp:
            fp.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)              # seek to end of file; f.seek(0, 2) is legal
            fp.seek(fp.tell() -5, os.SEEK_SET)   # go backwards 5 bytes
            fp.write(", \n")
            json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
            fp.close()  
        Window().__init__()
        self.close()
```

Here are all my files:

[Full Python File Code](https://pastebin.com/hef9N6Rq)

[Contacts.json](https://pastebin.com/hhV9MBMJ)

[CSS StyleSheet](https://pastebin.com/By3tDPRv)

[keyTestKey.txt](https://pastebin.com/3YGFYA7K)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `Window().__init__()` part makes no sense, equivalently the `AddContactWindow().__init__()` in the other class, since `__init__` is called automatically on construction, i.e. the `()` call to the class. Also the widget is not assigned to a variable, which may lead to the destructor getting called right away. Could have to do with the problem at least. Does it print anything on the stdout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- The following code: `Window() .__init__()` does not make sense, you are creating a new object, and you are resetting the same object that you just created, I suspect that you think that with this you are reloading the initial window, but.
- On the other hand in `submitBtn_click` you are overwriting the data with only one contact losing the initial format, what you should do is read the json, modify it and save it.
- You are creating objects every time and that is not the best, it is best to reuse, in my solution I only create one window of each class, and what I do is close or show the windows as required.
- Another problem that I see is that you are not using the layouts correctly.

Considering the previous thing, and others that are not so transcendental (I have not used keyCode since I do not have the .txt, I think that you can implement it)

```
import json
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        self.contact_window = AddContactWindow()
        self.contact_window.SubmitBtn.clicked.connect(self.loadContacts)
        self.contact_window.SubmitBtn.clicked.connect(self.show)

    def init_ui(self):
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.ContactLab = QtWidgets.QLabel('Contact')
        self.ContactDropDown = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.ContactDropDown.addItem('Please select a contact')

        lay.addWidget(self.ContactLab)
        lay.addWidget(self.ContactDropDown)
        lay.addStretch()
        self.ContactsFile = []
        self.loadContacts()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def loadContacts(self):
        with open('Contacts.json') as f:
            self.ContactsFile = json.load(f)
            self.ContactDropDown.clear()
            for contact in self.ContactsFile['contacts']:
                self.ContactDropDown.addItem(contact['Name'] + "/" + contact['CodeName'])
            self.ContactDropDown.addItem("Add new contact")

            self.setWindowTitle('Cipher Program')
            self.ContactDropDown.activated[str].connect(self.contactBtn_clk)
            self.show()

    def contactBtn_clk(self, text):
        for contact in self.ContactsFile['contacts']:
            if text == contact['Name'] + "/" + contact['CodeName']: 
                email = contact['Email']
                contactName = text
                # keyCode = open(r'KEYS\key' + contact['Key'] + '.txt', 'r').read()
                # key = bytes(self.KeyCode, 'utf-8')
            elif text == "Add new contact":
                self.contact_window.clear()
                self.contact_window.show()
                self.close()


class AddContactWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        # self.setStyleSheet(Window.StyleSheet1)

    def init_ui(self):
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Add New Contact'))
        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        lay.addLayout(flay)
        lay.addStretch()

        self.NameLe = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.CodeNameLe = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.EmailLe = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.KeyLe = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.SubmitBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add Contact')
        self.SubmitBtn.clicked.connect(self.submitBtn_click)

        flay.addRow("Name: ", self.NameLe)
        flay.addRow("Code Name: ", self.CodeNameLe)
        flay.addRow("Email address: ", self.EmailLe)
        flay.addRow("Key: ", self.KeyLe)
        flay.addRow(self.SubmitBtn)

        self.setWindowTitle('Creat New Contact')

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if self.isVisible():
            self.NameLe.setFocus()
        super(AddContactWindow, self).showEvent(event)

    def clear(self):
        self.NameLe.clear()
        self.CodeNameLe.clear()
        self.EmailLe.clear()
        self.KeyLe.clear()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def submitBtn_click(self):
        contact = dict()
        contact['Name'] = self.NameLe.text()
        contact['CodeName'] = self.CodeNameLe.text()
        contact['Email'] = self.EmailLe.text()
        contact['Key'] = self.KeyLe.text()
        with open('Contacts.json', 'r+') as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
            data["contacts"].append(contact)
            fp.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, fp, indent=4)
            fp.truncate()
        self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    with open('PyQt5 StyleSheet1 (Red, Black, and Blue).css', 'r') as styleSheet:
        qss = styleSheet.read()
        app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    a_window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This works very well, thank you so much. However having said that, the add contact window appears from the very start. Any idea how to fix that so it only shows when selecting 'add contact' from the drop down?

Comment: When I run the program, both windows appear immediately, I don't want the add contact window to appear unless I select add contact from the drop down. As far as selecting it from the drop down that works fine, its just appearing at the launch as well, and I dont want that.

Comment: This is what happens when I run the program: https://imgur.com/a/dgP6PIz (I added my other code, and changed your layout)

Comment: @JohnCooper The problem with your code is that you use show() in init_ui(), do not do it, remove self.show() in init_ui().

Answer (score 0):

Change the code between lines 218 and 219 to:

```
self.hide()
AddContactWindow().exec_()
self.show()

self.ContactDropDown.clear()
self.ContactDropDown.addItem('Please select a contact')
with open('Contacts.json') as f:
    self.ContactsFile = json.load(f)
for contact in self.ContactsFile['contacts']:
    print(contact)
    self.ContactDropDown.addItem(contact['Name'] + "/" + contact['CodeName'])
self.ContactDropDown.addItem("Add new contact")
```

Change the code in line 297 to be:

```
class AddContactWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
```

Change the code between lines 368 and 375 to:

```
ContactsFile = []
with open('Contacts.json', 'r') as fp:
    ContactsFile = json.load(fp)
    fp.close()
ContactsFile["contacts"].append(data)
with open('Contacts.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(ContactsFile, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    fp.close()
```

[Full Python File Code](https://pastebin.com/U3x4cyJv)